# How to export CSV and XLS with external button in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, export-to-csv

As you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/9pxurfga/

I have **export buttons outside** the chart, and I need to download data to **CSV** and **XLS**.

With highcharts export default button everything works fine : PNG, JPEG, CSV, XLS.

With my custom button **PNG** export is OK, but not the others.

I dont know how to use *exportChart* function for **CSV** and **XLS**, it seems to work only with image, but not with data/text format.

```
$('#button1').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.exportChartLocal({
        type: 'text/csv'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could call different function specified in the `export-data` module named `downloadCSV` and `downloadXLS`.

For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pxurfga/5/)):

```
// Export TO CSV
$('#button2').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.downloadCSV();
});

 // Export TO XLS
$('#button3').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.downloadXLS();
});
```

These functions do not use the export server.

Note that to get the same filename output for all buttons I had to add:

```
exporting: {
    filename: 'chart'
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! I did even see downloadCSV() on highcharts documentation...  thank you Halvor !!

Comment: And with Angular can we do or not